# df[column] = apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1]) behaves weirdly

Tags: python, pandas

Question is:
Why is the value of top_2_should different from top_2_is - or in other words - why is the outcome of the apply function wrong if it is assigned to a column?

EDIT: As I think that the question was slightly misunderstood, I created another example to it.
EDIT2: I use Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit) :: Pandas 0.18.0

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
     'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}
df52 = pd.DataFrame(d)

top_1_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
top_2_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1], 1)
df52['top_1_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
df52['top_1_should'] = top_1_should
df52['top_2_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1], 1)
df52['top_2_should'] = top_2_should
print df52

   one  two  top_1_is  top_1_should  top_2_is  top_2_should
0  1.0  4.0       1.0           1.0       1.0           4.0
1  2.0  3.0       2.0           2.0       2.0           3.0
2  3.0  2.0       2.0           2.0       2.0           3.0
3  4.0  1.0       1.0           1.0       1.0           4.0
```

Best,
Jan

Comment: As you add more columns to `df52`, `sort_values` will return a different series, and indexing into this series will produce different results. You might want to use `sort_values()[-1]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for break align rows:

```
print (df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values().values, axis=1))
   one  two
0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  1.0  4.0
```

Or:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df52.values), df52.index, df52.columns))
   one  two
0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  1.0  4.0
```

---

If use `print`, you get output of sorting - if add new columns before, need change position of selected row in `Series` what is column in `DataFrame`:

```
top_1_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
top_2_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1], 1)
df52['top_1_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
df52['top_1_should'] = top_1_should
df52['top_2_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1], 1)
df52['top_2_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: print(row.sort_values()), 1)
one             1.0
top_1_is        1.0
top_1_should    1.0
top_2_is        1.0
two             4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
one             2.0
top_1_is        2.0
top_1_should    2.0
top_2_is        2.0
two             3.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
two             2.0
top_1_is        2.0
top_1_should    2.0
top_2_is        2.0
one             3.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
two             1.0
top_1_is        1.0
top_1_should    1.0
top_2_is        1.0
one             4.0
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
     'two' : [2., 3., 4., 5.]}
df52 = pd.DataFrame(d)

top_1_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
top_2_should = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[1], 1)
df52['top_1_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[0], 1)
df52['top_1_should'] = top_1_should
df52['top_2_is'] = df52.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values()[3], 1)
df52['top_2_should'] = top_2_should
print(df52)
```

Returns:

```
  one  two  top_1_is  top_1_should  top_2_is  top_2_should
0    1    2         1             1         2             2
1    2    3         2             2         3             3
2    3    4         3             3         4             4
3    4    5         4             4         5             5
```

Comment: Python3.5, Pandas 0.17.1